# Unable to swap primary OAuth ID with a secondary one

Tags: bug, authentication

I am on the user profile screen and am unable to swap my primary OAuth ID with a second one and a pop up shows up confirming that however when I click OK, the ID never seems to get swapped.

Comment: Which website are you referring too? I ran into this same issue where I couldn't swap my Open IDs for StackCareer. The request threw a 500 HTTP error.